# why am i getting a php fatal error for calling the same function twice?

Tags: php, pdo

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZNlAyky7TzT4jknpnoDJ?p=preview

here is a link to a plnkr with all my code written so far. I keep getting an

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare connect_to_db() (previously declared in
>   /var/www/html/News/config/dbconnect.php:5) in
>   /var/www/html/News/config/dbconnect.php on line 5

the plunkr wont have the folder structure because i could not figure out how to add folders however here is my code for dbconnect.php

```
 <?php
        $pdo = null;
        function connect_to_db()
        {
            $dbengine   = 'mysql';
            $dbhost     = 'localhost';
            $dbuser     = 'root';
            $dbpassword = 'password';
            $dbname     = 'news';

            try{
                $pdo = new PDO("".$dbengine.":host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser,$dbpassword);
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                return $pdo;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e){
                $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

line 5 does not have a call to db connect so i dont know what is going on

Comment: You are including the file containing connect_to_db() more than once. Use require_once or include_once instead of require and include should fix your problem.

Comment: The problem isn't for calling the same function twice, it's for *defining* it twice.

Comment: You are not _calling_ the function twice, you _define_ it twice.

Comment: so use this structure ?

Comment: <?php 
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php'); 
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
require __DIR__.'/dbconnect.php'
```

In both your Index.php and your functions.php, while requiring your functions.php in Index.php.

Therefore `connect_to_db()` is being defined twice. Use `require_once` instead to prevent this:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/dbconnect.php'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: i have to wait the couple of minutes then i will mark as answered!